# Nested for loops and repeated iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following nested `for` loops. I am having trouble figuring out why when the inner `for` loop exits, the outer `for` loop attempts to increment the iterator when clearly it should not be doing so. This results in a seg fault. Why would the outer for loop continue running if it has the condition `cbeg != vec.cend()`. Clearly that condition was checked in the inner `for` loop with no problem, and it exited correctly.

I don't believe any iterators are being invalidated here, the only operation is an increment.

```
vector<int> vec{1,2,3,4};

for (auto cbeg = vec.cbegin(); cbeg != vec.cend(); cbeg++)
{
   for (; cbeg != vec.cend(); cbeg++) {
   }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/stmt.for#1) and see what the equivalent while loop would look like. `expression` (`cbeg++`) is executed after the loop body, and in this case the loop body sets `cbeg` to `vec.cend()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reaching `}` increments the iterator, and **then** checks the condition.

When inner loop exits, `cbeg == vec.cend()`. Then `cbeg` is incremented again by the outer loop, resulting in undefined behaviour before the condition of the outer loop could be checked.

Comment: Holy moly, can not believe I missed something so fundamental. Was going through it for a solid hour :X